# Identify a port on a SATA-to-USB Adapter

Tags: usb, sata, connection, adapter

I'm searching for a good SATA-to-USB adapter. I found [this one on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005B3VO24) which seems to have pretty good reviews. However the connector that the USB cable plugs into has a shape that I've never seen before. I'm hoping to get one that has a standard connector so I can replace the cable if it gets damaged. Does anyone know if this is a standard connector?

Here is an image of the product. You can see the data connector on the left side.

[image: SATA to USB adapter]

Comment: Looks like an ordinary USB 3.0 micro-B connector to me.  Were you expecting a USB 2.0 connector instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a standard USB 3.0 Micro-B connector.

https://www.cablestogo.com/learning/connector-guides/usb#3-0-micro-b

Also, in some devices these ports on devices are also backwards compatible with USB 2.0 Micro-USB cable if they have low enough power requirements or external power.

Comment: Thanks I just googled USB3 and saw the micro-b connector right away. I'll accept as soon as it lets me.

Comment: A standard micro-USB 3.0 port should be always compatible with micro USB2 cables.